# Creating data validation list with indirect formula through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation, macros, excel-indirect

Usually the record option in Excel is great but this time it didn't help.

I can create a Data Validation List through VBA with this Code:

```
Sub Macro 8()

With Range("C8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Land"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Now this works. But in the Cell underneath I need the formula to be `=INDIRECT($C$8)`. So using the Recorder I got pretty much the same Code:

```
Sub Macro1()

With Range("C9").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect($C$8)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

But using that code I always get an "application-defined or object-defined error" pointing to the line

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect($C$8)"
```

Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly right. You don't need a lot of code to do the Indirect() part. Here is the whole thing:

```
Sub Macro8()

With Range("C8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Land"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Range("C9").Formula = "=INDIRECT(""$C$8"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for the answer!
I need the INDIRECT cell to be a drop down too...
If I do it manually it works since The Values I get from C8 are the names of Lists in my worksheet, so I get the selection from that list in C9

With just inserting =INDIRECT($C$8) it doesn't work...
Any Idea?

Comment: You have to use =Indirect("$C$8"). Beyond that, I'd consider this question answered. For any further issues, it's best to start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

I put my existing code in a separate macro and made it relative to ActiveCell

now it runs whenever something is selected in the cell above

Thanks tho!